# Having trouble working with CoreData Flow

Tags: swift, core-data

I want to store some data from json at core data for letting user to see permanent on device which is being received from a web service. But I really need to know that my process flow is right or not.

**What I was doing now**

1. Web Server Response -> JSON -> parse to -> save to `NSManagedObject`?
2. And then fetch items from core data -> show in a `UITableView`

**All I want is simple,**

1. Get the JSON from api
2. Store records in iPhone Database/CoreData.
3. After storing that, show user the data using a `UITableView` without clearing it when application is closed and the user can delete and fetch new results from web service.
4. And I will set 50 results maximum. When they are full at max length, it will be **FILO(First In Last Out)** of records.

I have done fetching and parsing results from web API with my app before. But, using core data is strange to me. So, if I am going in the wrong way, can you guide me.

**Is my CoreData data-flow correct?**

Comment: Can you add some example code of how you are using CoreData and Screenshots of you entitlements file...

Comment: I am sorry to say that I cant show some code or entities.I only need to know the flow process that I am doing is right or not.

Comment: The flow is fine, it's up to you if you want to use CoreData. If you feel more comfortable you could create a SQL Database, it's all down to preference.